# Polling using expand in rxjs gives an unexpected result

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am trying to setup a poller using expand but the behavior is not what I want

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-finalize-unsubscribe-6xy2yb?file=index.ts

checkExistence produces a random boolean - With the expand, I expect a recursive delayed call of the same checkExistence function producing random booleans every 5 seconds (after one initial call).

I also expect the stop to kick in 30seconds and stop the polling and 5 seconds later resume the random boolean stream. Any pointers will help.

Instead I get the same boolean value getting printed; also after the start is triggered, it produces batches of booleans together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a single question.

## Assignment/function Invocation

#### A simplified example

The equals operator assigns a value to a variable. Function invocation returns a value

```ts
function inc(n){
  return n + 1
}

const result = inc(5)
console.log(result); // 6
```

Here, the result holds the number value 6. Not a function that calculated 5 + 1. 5 + 1 only happens once here.

Now consider this function that randomly increments a number by either 1 or 2

```ts
function bump(n){
  const nu = Math.random();
  return nu < 0.5 ? n + 1 : n + 2 
}

const result = bump(5);
console.log(result); // 7
console.log(result); // 7 
console.log(result); // 7 
console.log(result); // 7 
console.log(result); // 7
```

Every time I print the result, it's the same. `bump` was only called once and only generated a random number once.

```ts
function bump(n){
  const nu = Math.random();
  return nu < 0.5 ? n + 1 : n + 2 
}

console.log(bump(5)); // 7
console.log(bump(5)); // 7 
console.log(bump(5)); // 6 
console.log(bump(5)); // 7 
console.log(bump(5)); // 6
```

Here, `bump` is called 5 times, and each time it generated a new random number.

## Fixing checkExistence

There are two ways.

- Instead of generating a value once and re-using it. Generate a new boolean in your poll every time you need one.

```ts
function checkExistencePoll(): Observable<boolean> {
  const POLL = 5000;
  return checkExistence().pipe(
    expand(_ =>
      timer(POLL).pipe(
        switchMap(() => checkExistence()),
        takeUntil(stop),
        repeatWhen(() => start)
      )
    )
  );
}
```

- Have `checkExistence` return an observable that generates a new boolean on subscription

```ts
function checkExistence(): Observable<boolean> {
  return defer(() => {
    const nu = Math.random();
    const rand = nu < 0.5;
    console.log(nu, rand);
    return of(rand);
  });
}
```

---

## Handling subscriptions

In your code, `expand` is generating an observable that subscribes to a subject ( called `start`) in order to decide when to repeat. Every observable `expand` creates does this. So each one repeats when `start` emits. You should expect *batches* of booleans equal to the number of concurrent observables you've created.